How to Separate Data with Inconsistent Patterns into a Structured Format in Excel
Inconsistent Values in Cells
I'm working with a dataset where multiple values in a cell are tagged under categories like Location, Host, Guest, and Bucket, and separated by line breaks. I need to split these into separate columns based on the tags, but the values are inconsistent, so separating by line break creates many unwanted columns.
Below are some cells that I want to format in a specific way (see format style image attached below)



Location / Hosts / Guests / Regulars / Musicians / Band Members / Bucket Pulls




Location: Comedy Store Belly RoomHost: Tony HinchcliffeHost: Brian RedbanGuest: Rick IngrahamBucket: SkylerBucket: Rich SlatonBucket: Jeff SchwindBucket: Matt DevlinBucket: Taylor DeanBucket: Frank CastilloBucket: Kenny LionBucket: Mike StanleyBucket: Andrew YankerBucket: Sara MostajabiBucket: Timothy GreerBucket: Kyle Henson


Location: Comedy Store Main RoomHost: Tony HinchcliffeHost: Brian RedbanGuest: Joe RoganGuest: Dom IrreraMusical Guest: Pat ReganMusical Guest: Jeremiah WatkinsSecurity: Iron PatriotBucket: Chris FriedBucket: Dan MadoniaBucket: Gail TraversBucket: Chalus RobinsonBucket: Dan BublitzBucket: Mike FairbareBucket: Eddie GibsonRegular: Sara WeinshenkRegular: Kim Congdon


Location: Comedy Store Belly RoomHost: Tony HinchcliffeHost: Brian RedbanGuest: Chris D’EliaGuest: Neal BrennanMusical Guest: Pat ReganArtist: Ryan J. EbeltBucket Signups: 30Bucket: Matty ChymborBucket: David DeeryBucket: Franklin YeeBucket: Cole YoungBucket: Gali KroupBucket: Jeremy PaulBucket: Tim AlexanderBucket: Mike SchmidtRegular: Sara WeinshenkBucket: Eddie Gibson



Format Style Snippet
Used a Delimiter
When I use a delimiter to separate the data, it works well for the Location and Host columns because they are similar throughout the column, but the other values (like Guest and Bucket) are inconsistent across cells, so they spill into different columns after separation. This is causing issues when trying to structure the data correctly.
I've already cleaned most of the dataset, but I'm stuck on how to handle these inconsistent patterns. I have spent hours trying to figure it out, tried using different formulas like textsplit,wrapcols,wraprows, etc but to no avail. I am so frustrated please help.
Could you suggest the best way to tackle this? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

start by providing a representative data sample as text which can be copy/pasted and then a screenshot of what you expect for results from that same data.

The start of the google-sheets tag wiki says Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead. This holds true for Excel as well. We can't do anything with the images you've dumped here. They're only difficult to see, but we can't copy any of the text to use to try to find a solution.

Use this tool to create your markdown table: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables. It appears Location is always  the start of a new record. Correct?

Yes Location is always the start of new record

I am new on this platform, and it seems like I have to be precise with the dataset when asking questions, I'll be providing cell data and the outcome I am expecting in a short while when I come back from university.

Assuming a starting table of as you have it above, you can perform the following steps:

Add an Index column
Split column in rows by newline

Optional (if you really need this under Bucket) Replace value Bucket Signups: with Bucket: Bucket Signups:

Split column again but now to Columns by :   and left most:

Trim values
Group by and Combine values

Then you will need to update the formula bar, replace:

List.Sum([Value])

with
Text.Combine([Value], ", ")


Pivot on Category column


To give you are resulting table of:



Index
Location
Host
Guest
Bucket
Musical Guest
Security
Regular
Artist




1
Comedy Store Belly Room
Tony Hinchcliffe, Brian Redban
Rick Ingraham
Skyler, Rich Slaton, Jeff Schwind, Matt Devlin, Taylor Dean, Frank Castillo, Kenny Lion, Mike Stanley, Andrew Yanker, Sara Mostajabi, Timothy Greer, Kyle Henson






2
Comedy Store Main Room
Tony Hinchcliffe, Brian Redban
Joe Rogan, Dom Irrera
Chris Fried, Dan Madonia, Gail Travers, Chalus Robinson, Dan Bublitz, Mike Fairbare, Eddie Gibson
Pat Regan, Jeremiah Watkins
Iron Patriot
Sara Weinshenk, Kim Congdon



3
Comedy Store Belly Room
Tony Hinchcliffe, Brian Redban
Chris D’Elia, Neal Brennan
Bucket Signups: 30, Matty Chymbor, David Deery, Franklin Yee, Cole Young, Gali Kroup, Jeremy Paul, Tim Alexander, Mike Schmidt, Eddie Gibson
Pat Regan

Sara Weinshenk
Ryan J. Ebelt



From here, you can decide which columns to keep, rename, reorder etc...
Full Power Query:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Location / Hosts / Guests / Regulars / Musicians / Band Members / Bucket Pulls", type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index", {{"Location / Hosts / Guests / Regulars / Musicians / Band Members / Bucket Pulls", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Location / Hosts / Guests / Regulars / Musicians / Band Members / Bucket Pulls"),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Split Column by Delimiter","Bucket Signups:","Bucket: Bucket Signups:",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Location / Hosts / Guests / Regulars / Musicians / Band Members / Bucket Pulls"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Location / Hosts / Guests / Regulars / Musicians / Band Members / Bucket Pulls", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({":"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Category", "Value"}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Value", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Trimmed Text", {"Index", "Category"}, {{"Values", each Text.Combine([Value], ", "), type text}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Grouped Rows", List.Distinct(#"Grouped Rows"[Category]), "Category", "Values")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"


My initial dataset doesn't have "Event" column instead it only has "Location / Hosts / Guests / Regulars / Musicians / Band Members / Bucket Pulls" or "Your Column" in the above answer
I tried this solution, and while it's very close to what I need, it's not giving me the correct output due to a slight difference. Please help me adjust it to get the desired result.
I have edited my question to make it more easier to understand.

No worries about not having the Event column, this can be solved by adding an Index column as the first step. I will update the answer with the same, but first, please highlight how my solution is not giving the desired result due to slight differences.

Updated answer above to include the initial Index step, and added step 3 above Replace Value if you really need Bucket Signups to come under Bucket.

When I groupby, I get error in 3rd column -- Everything else is perfectly aligned horizontally
After splitting the data 2nd time, I got 3 columns I named them Event (index), Category, Value (names).

Do you want to share more details on the error you are getting on the 3rd column? Do note the additional modification of the formula in Step 6 Group By. The Group By UI doesn't have the option Combine Text values.

Error below:
Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator - to types Text and Text.
Details:
Operator=-
Left=Comedy Store Belly Room
Right=Comedy Store Belly Room
This is the error I get in most of the cells in the 3rd column, only instance where error doesn't occur is when the value is null.

I don't have any instances of - in the above code. Which step is this error occurring and maybe share the Power Query code you have (via Advanced Editor). How are you loading the data (table) into Power Query?

I pasted your Query Code and it worked just fine, I'll investigate this code, and try to understand it. If I can't get my head around this can I ask for clarification?
Cannot thank you enough, you have made my days. I was stuck on it for the past 2 days, I Spent around 20 hours trying to figure.
Really really appreciate it. Thanks a lot!!!!
